# What last layer should be in multi label classification?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning

Why do I need to use the `sigmoid` function instead of the `softmax` in the last layer if I switch from multiclass to multi label classification?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Theoretically speaking softmax will sum up to 1 for a given input. This makes sense in the case of a single class per input, i.e. the target vector sums up to 1.

However, in the case of multiple classes per input, the output sums up to the numer of labels per input. In this case you would like to know the percentage on how likely your input has a given class. This is accomplished by a sigmoid function. Sigmoid gives you a value between 0 and 1 and those values are independant between different classes for a single input.

There are other functions  which provides values between 0 and 1 (for example 0.5*(tanh(x) + 1)), but sigmoid has been proven to work well in practice and is therefore used for multilabel classification.